# How to force compiler to use one core only?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, mingw

I noticed, that MingW and GCC compilers use multiple cores if available.

For example:

```
for (long i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
{
    some_complicated_calculation();
}
```

If I open up a Task Manager / System Monitor, I can see that multiple (for me: 2) cores are used.

How the compiler decides, which code can run on multiple cores?
How do I force the compiler, to use only one core?

EDIT

My code does not contain any multithreaded code.
I'm curious why my program (not the compiler) is using multiple cores.

Comment: It may be your operating system dispatching the process to different cores.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/AutoParInGCC

Comment: Just to be clear - are you talking about the compiler using multiple cores (i.e. compiling in parallel), or about your program using multiple cores (i.e. runnin multi-threaded)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is using a single core as long as there is nothing special inside some_complicated_calculation() that creates threads or uses async (C++11) or similar.

The activity you see on the task manager cannot be related to the executable that iterates. It could be totally unrelated to what you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like thread_bind_to_processor provided in GNU software radio is what you're looking for:
http://gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/namespacegr_1_1thread.html#aab5195edcd94db5c71ecbfef9d578fb7